# How to remove URL and keep path only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I remove the URL from a string but keep the path only?

I just want to keep the path only but API returns FULL URL only.

```
MainMenu.jsx:47 http://dev.ffbvps.local/about/
MainMenu.jsx:47 http://dev.ffbvps.local/work/
MainMenu.jsx:47 http://dev.ffbvps.local/behind-the-scenes/
MainMenu.jsx:47 http://dev.ffbvps.local/people/
MainMenu.jsx:47 http://dev.ffbvps.local/themes/
```

Comment: hi Nino. Can you put here also the part of the code that returns this to you. If you have put here the result of console.log, could you put that part of the code that you are logging?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const paramUrl = new URL("http://dev.ffbvps.local/about/");
console.log(paramUrl.pathname)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the pathname, you can use:

```
window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

let url

```js
let urlObjPath = new URL("http://dev.ffbvps.local/behind-the-scenes/").pathname;
console.log(urlObjPath);
```